# Android mediaplayer loop with a timedelay

Tags: android

How can i play a song in my android mediaplayer in a loop but with a timedelay or a small pause between each time it starts the song again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Handler` with the `postDelayed` method.

Comment: Yeah I thought if there was any other way than using postdelayed.Anyways i ended up using that only. Thanks :)